# Powershell to compare output with a CSV file?

Tags: powershell, csv, comparison

I am using the code below to get a list of computer names where they were last modified 181 days ago. I have a .csv file with 2 columns (ComputerName, UserName) Is there a way I can match the output from the code below with the computername column in the csv file and show the output/matches?

```
$Days = (Get-Date).AddDays(-181) 

Get-ADComputer -Property Name,lastLogonDate -Filter  {lastLogonDate -lt $Days} -Server DomainController -Searchbase "OU=US,DC=contoso,DC=net" | FT Name,lastLogonDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `... | FT Name,lastLogonDate` to `... | select Name,lastLogonDate`. You can still pipe the result into `ft` to format it as a table, but separating selection from presentation will make it easier to put in additional filters.

For displaying just the computers that have matches in your CSV you could do the following:

```
$computers = Import-Csv 'your.csv' | % { $_.ComputerName }

Get-ADComputer -Property Name,lastLogonDate ... | select Name,lastLogonDate |
    ? { $computers -contains $_.Name } | ft
```

To include the username from the CSV with the result you could do something like this:

```
$computers = @{}
Import-Csv 'your.csv' | % { $computers[$_.ComputerName] = $_.UserName }

Get-ADComputer -Property Name,lastLogonDate ... |
    ? { $computers.Keys -contains $_.Name } |
    select Name,lastLogonDate,@{n='Username';e={$computers[$_.Name]}} | ft
```

Comment: Thanks, the code is working but how do I show the username column from the csv next to the computername? I am not sure how to do that ft Name, Username?

Comment: What does this line do? % { $_.Computer_Name }

Comment: That's a `ForEach-Object` loop, which creates a list (array) of computer names. The modified version uses a hashtable instead, with the computer names as keys and the user names as values.

Comment: For some reason the Employee_Name column in the output is only displaying {} on each row. Any idea why its not returning the employee name?